# How to append item in array inside object inside object in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this kind of state:

```
{
'guy1': {...},
'guy2':{...},
'guy3: {'key1': [...], 'key2': [...]}
}
```

I want to append an item inside key2.

I tried all of these **(none of these worked)**:

`guy3: {...prevState.guy3, key2: prevState.guy3.key2.concat([item])}`

OR

`guy3: {...prevState.guy3, key2: [...prevState.guy3.key2, item]}`

OR

```
let key2 = this.state.guy3.key2.slice();
key2.push(item);
this.setState(prevState => {
   guy3: {...prevState.guy3, key2}
};
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Won't just `this.state.guy3.key2.push(item)` be enough ?

Comment: @Titus That breaks immutability. At minimum you'd need `...key2.slice().push(item)`

Comment: IMO there's nothing wrong with solution 2

Comment: @mhodges None of those work including solution 2. It doesn't make any change to state. idk why.

Comment: @NaMo Have you tried `guy3: Object.assign({}, prevState.guy3, {key2: [...prevState.guy3.key2, item]});`?

Comment: @mhodges nope. Didn't work.

Comment: @NaMo Hmm.. Can you post more of your code? This may be an issue relating to the surrounding code.

Comment: @trincot It's non-working code, so I don't think it would go over too well at [codereview.se]...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I have updated the question accordingly & retracted vote.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
   ...prevState, 
   guy3: {
      ...prevState.guy3,
      key2: [...prevState.guy3.key2, item] 
   }
}));
```

Or, make use of an API for easily creating updated objects while keeping with immutability. For example [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper):

```
this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, { guy3: { key2: {$push: item} } }));
```